# Interpretación de un código en Python

Tags: python

necesito una ayuda. Podrían ayudarme a interpretar la lógica de esta sección de código. Tengo dudas sobre el uso del def get_row. En si, que está realizando este código?

```
def get_row(initial_column,length):
    col = initial_column
    row = []
    while col < len(coeff):
        row.append(coeff[col])
        col+=2
    if row[-1] != 0:
        row.append(0)
 
    if length > 0:
        while len(row) != length:
            row.append(0)
    return row
```

Answer (score 0):

Agreguemos la lista `coeff` que falta en tu problema y probemos:

```
def get_row(initial_column, length):
    col = initial_column
    row = []
    while col < len(coeff):
        row.append(coeff[col])
        col += 2
    if row[-1] != 0:
        row.append(0)

    if length > 0:
        while len(row) != length:
            row.append(0)
    return row

coeff = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
x = get_row(2, 4)
print(x)
```

produce

```
[3, 5, 7, 0]
```

Conclusión: `get_row` retorna una lista de largo `length` con elementos tomados de `coeff`. La lista toma elementos de dos en dos a partir de la posición dada por `initial_column`. La lista se completa con elementos en cero hasta completar el largo pedido.